# CQLEngineException when running inside VPN

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cqlengine

I keep getting this error when using django-cassandra-engine on a EC2 instance inside a VPN.

```
CQLEngineException: It is required to setup() cqlengine before executing queries.
```

It seems to run properly when running on a EC2 instance outside the VPN.
The configuration I'm using is this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'stgks',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_db',
        'HOST': '172.95.95.343',
    }
}
```

There are two other nodes in the ring that contain the specified host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the incompatible versions of Django, cassandra-driver and Django-cassandra-engine. Correcting the versions worked out

Comment: Which versions exactly worked for you. I am using Django 1.6.3 and django-cassandra-engine==0.3.2

Comment: I am using Django 1.7 and django-cassandra-engine 0.4